Re-ordering CiviRules Actions
I have a CiviRule with a large number of actions, all in a sequence with delays.  I want to insert an action in the middle of the sequence.  When I do "Add Action" it puts the action at the end of the list (very reasonably).  Is it true that there is no "move up" or "reorder" capability for actions?  I have tried Google and searching here but cannot find anything pointing to this.
I'm interpreting this to mean that if I'm editing a CiviRule and I need to put a new action in the middle of a series of actions, I basically need to delete and recreate anything that would come after the point where I want to insert the new action?
I hesitate to ask but is there a database manual edit hack around this even?  Something I can do programmatically with an API call?
Thank you

Did you play around with the delay - i.e. using delay as order? I can't find any db field to hold order information.

@nielo - Isn't delay the delay versus the prior action?  Or is it delay versus the very first action?  That ... I hadn't considered that possibility!

@nielo You are right - delay is from the event that triggered (https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-delay/) -- so I could edit the delay to reorder the actions.  They would not be listed in order in the list of actions, so you'd have to read the list of actions carefully, but it's better than nothing.  Thank you!  If you want to put this as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Feel free to answer yourself, it was just an educated guess and you did the investigation :)
